# Complicated Cross-Table Query

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm in need of help to build a query. Problem is, i dont have permissions to make design changes to the DB. With that in mind, my tables look like this:

`Problems`
ID
Date
LastStory
UserAssignedTo

`Stories`
ID
ProblemID
UserThatMadeTheStory
DateOfStory
Status

How is Data Stored:
Any user on the System can create a "Problem". Each time a problem is created, There's also a row inserted on the table Stories, linking to the "ProblemID" of the Problems table, with an Status of "2" and with "UserThatMadeTheStory" assigned to the actual user that made the "Problem".
Later on, the problem is "Reasigned" to other users. This process Creates an "Stories" entry, with a description and with the "UserThatMadeTheStory" Changed to the user that assigned it, at the same time, in the "Problems" table the "UserAssignedTo" is changed to save the new user is assigned to.
Then, to know WHO actually opened the Problem I have to look for the FIRST record in "Stories" that has the "ProblemID" matching the one i want to know.

Now, the problem i have is this:

I Have to lookup for, lets say, last month, Problems created by an user.
How will it be the query?

EDIT:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN (SELECT problemid, min(id) AS Id FROM stories GROUP BY problemid) s2 ON s.id = s2.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserThatMadeTheStory, DateOfStory, Id FROM stories) s3 ON s2.id = s3.id
WHERE s3.UserThatMadeTheStory = <the one you're interested in>
AND s3.DateOfStory = <dates you're interested in>
```

This does work as intended, now i have nother issue...

> If you can help me... I have to LIST the Problems that have been CREATED by X user. AND HAVENT got ANY "stories" in lets say "Last 2 days" (Or any date specified [It can be an external input to the query])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN (SELECT problemid, min(id) FROM stories GROUP BY problemid) s2 ON s.id = s2.id
WHERE s2.UserThatMadeTheStory = <the one you're interested in>
AND s2.DateOfStory = <dates you're interested in>
```

EDIT:

Actually, there are some errors in the above SQL - sorry about that. I've amended it so it should work now. Note, I've had to add a third join to ensure that you get the User/Date that the issue was first logged:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN (SELECT problemid, min(id) AS Id FROM stories GROUP BY problemid) s2 ON s.id = s2.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserThatMadeTheStory, DateOfStory, Id FROM stories) s3 ON s2.id = s3.id
WHERE s3.UserThatMadeTheStory = <the one you're interested in>
AND s3.DateOfStory = <dates you're interested in>
```

Edit 2:

For your new problem (which should really be posted on a new question):

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM stories s
INNER JOIN (SELECT problemid, min(id) AS Id FROM stories GROUP BY problemid) s2 ON s.id = s2.id
INNER JOIN (SELECT UserThatMadeTheStory, DateOfStory, Id FROM stories) s3 ON s2.id = s3.id
INNER JOIN problems p ON s.problemid = p.id
WHERE s3.UserThatMadeTheStory = <the one you're interested in>
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stories s4 WHERE s4.problemid = p.id AND s4.id <> s2.id AND DATEDIFF(dd,s4.DateOfStory,GETDATE()) <= 2)
```

Comment: This DID work as intended. I had to make some modifications to the query because of some minimal errors (As using "min (id) as ID) and the final "Where s2.UserThatMadeTheStory" and "s2.DateOfStory" had to be changed to "s." instead of s2

Comment: using s.UserThatMadeTheStory won't give you back the user that originally raised the problem. I've edited my answer - give that a try..

Comment: Corrected. Working as a charm now. Thanks for the correction.
Now i have a bigger problem If you can help me...
I have to LIST the Problems that have been CREATED by X user. AND HAVENT got ANY "stories" in lets say "48hours" (Or any date specified)

Comment: I've edited this again with an answer to your new question. Going forward, if you have a different question, you should post it in a new thread. Its not good practice to un-accept previously (correctly) answered questions.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know the specific rules, or common uses of the site. Thank you again for answering my question and helping me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will want to use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
    MIN(ID),
    MIN(ProblemID)
FROM
    Stories
GROUP BY
    ID,
    ProblemID
```

the above for example should give you the first ID with the ProblemID for each story